# QStandardItemModel doesn't emit rowsMoved() signal on QTreeView InternalMove

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

I've got a `QTreeView` populated by a `QStandardItemModel` with the `TreeView` set up so it only allows internal Drag and Drop (InternalMove).
I am trying to detect whenever the user makes such an internal move and would like to extract the item being dragged as well as the start and end location.

`QStandardItemModel` provides the "`rowsMoved`" signal which is supposed to emit precisely what I am looking for: parent, start, end, destination, row.
The problem: This signal never gets called when moving around items. Why is this?

Other signals like `rowsInserted()` or `rowsRemoved()` work just fine, but `rowsMoved()` does not.

In the following minimal example, the `print()` in `onMove()` should be called when the user moves around items, but it doesn't.

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(view)

        view.setModel(model)

        root_item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Root")
        model.appendRow(root_item)

        self.populate(root_item, 3)
        view.expandAll()

        view.setDragEnabled(True)
        view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        view.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        view.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        model.rowsMoved.connect(self.onMove)  
    
    def onMove(self, parent, start, end, destination, row):
        print("parent",parent,"start",start,"end",end,"destination",destination,"row",row)

    def populate(self, root_item, level):
        for i in range(random.randint(2, 4)):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("item {}".format(i))
            it.setCheckable(False)
            root_item.appendRow(it)
            next_level = level - 1
            if next_level > 0:
                self.populate(it, next_level)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why did you delete your previous post and repost it with the same information? that is annoying and can be considered noise. You are abusing the system

Comment: Sorry about that! I had to edit the previous post a bunch of times and thought I would just repost it in its proper form.

Comment: no, the system is created so that the OP makes substantial edits whenever it wants. Many times some OPs think that reposting will get more positive attention but the truth is that they get the opposite. I prefer to see a post with many editions of the OP that shows that he has worked on his post than a noisy repost.

Comment: Alright sorry about that, won't do that again!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

```
Components connected to this signal use it to adapt to changes
in the model's dimensions. It can only be emitted by the QAbstractItemModel
implementation, and cannot be explicitly emitted in subclass code.
```

Considering that this signal is not defined by the `QStandardItemModel` class, any instance of this class won't emit such signal.
The only signals you can connect to, as you mentioned, are `rowsInserted()` are `rowsRemoved()` because they are redefined in this class. Note that they are marked as `internal` in the source file.

If you need information about the item being dragged, I suggest that you create a custom class which inherit from `QtWidgets.QTreeView` and override the `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` methods.

Here is an example on how to retrieve the item with its whole hierarchy being dragged and dropped:

```py
import random
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def getHierarchy(index, hierarchy=None):
    hierarchy = hierarchy or []
    if not index.isValid():
        return hierarchy
    hierarchy.insert(0, (index.row(), index.column()))
    return getHierarchy(index.parent(), hierarchy)


class MyTreeView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        super().dropEvent(e)
        currentIndex = e.source().currentIndex()
        print('dropEvent.source current index:', getHierarchy(currentIndex))

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        super().dragEnterEvent(e)
        currentIndex = e.source().currentIndex()
        print('dragEnterEvent.source current index:', getHierarchy(currentIndex))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        view = MyTreeView()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(view)

        view.setModel(model)

        root_item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Root")
        model.appendRow(root_item)

        self.populate(root_item, 3)
        view.expandAll()

        view.setDragEnabled(True)
        view.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        view.setDefaultDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        view.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)

    def populate(self, root_item, level):
        for i in range(random.randint(2, 4)):
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem("item {}".format(i))
            it.setCheckable(False)
            root_item.appendRow(it)
            next_level = level - 1
            if next_level > 0:
                self.populate(it, next_level)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I suggest to look at this repository which deals with a similar problem as yours: https://github.com/d1vanov/PyQt5-reorderable-list-model